# Padding for SecureRandom and URLsafe

Tags: ruby

I am trying to find a way to create a padding for a key created using:

`SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(8)`. I know I can pass a second argument stating that I want a padding, but according to the docs:

> The boolean argument padding specifies the padding. If it is false or
>   nil, padding is not generated. Otherwise padding is generated. By
>   default, padding is not generated because “=” may be used as a URL
>   delimiter.

So, my question is. How could I add a padding (that is url safe) so I know when is the string finished? (I need to concat two of those strings)

Answer (score 0):

from the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-urlsafe_base64):

> The result may contain `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, “`-`” and “`_`”

so you could use any other character for your delimiter, like `+` for example (which is a url-encoded space)